# Manually configure and start Crashlytics on iOS

Tags: ios, crashlytics

Crashlytics hooks itself into the build process with the Fabric run script in a last run script phase.

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"
```

However, I would prefer to configure and launch it during runtime for various reasons. One reason is the fact that the script is expecting the GoogleService-Info.plist in place, however I have slight variations in naming and atm it is not feasible to create new targets. Is there any way to achieve this?

Firebase itself offers a solution for this by providing

```
FirebaseApp.configure(options: FirebaseController.options(for: AnEnvironment.debug))
```

Answer (score 2):

Fabric/Firebase here-

The fabric includes a tool to automatically upload your project’s dSYM. The tool is executed through the /run script, which is added to your Run Script Build Phase during the onboarding process.

As an alternative to the automated dSYM upload tool, Fabric provides a command-line tool (upload-symbols) that can be manually configured to run as part of your project’s build process. See the [upload-symbols section](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#upload-symbols) for configuration instructions :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Generally answers without examples are considered low quality. You may consider adding additional examples to create a more robust answer.

Comment: This doesn't refer to my question at all.